# Validate 2Col syntax!

Tags: code-golf, string, decision-problem

As a couple of people may have noticed lately, I've largely abandoned development of [Braingolf](https://github.com/gunnerwolf/braingolf) because it's boring and uninspired, and moved on to [2Col](https://github.com/gunnerwolf/2col) which is a little more interesting, and not designed to be a golfing language.

The defining feature of 2Col is that every line of code must be exactly 2 characters long, excluding the newline. This means that the length of a 2Col program can always be calculated as `3n-1` where `n` is the number of lines in the program.

So here's my challenge: Given 2Col code as a string, output truthy if it is valid 2Col code (Every line is exactly 2 characters and it conforms with the `3n-1` formula), and falsey otherwise.

### Input

Input should be taken as a single string, or an array of characters.

### Output

A truthy value if the input string is valid layout, and a falsey value otherwise.

Your code should be consistent in which truthy/falsey values it uses

### Testcases

```
======
F!
$^
----
truthy
======


======
*8
+1
Sq
----
truthy
======


======
nop
xt
----
falsey
======


======
+1
+1
#^

----
falsey
======


======
<empty string>
----
falsey
======


======
ye
----
truthy
======


======
no<space>
----
falsey
======


======
test
----
falsey
======


======
puzzle
----
falsey
======
```

### Scoring

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf) so fewest bytes wins!

Comment: @Shaggy no, not unless for some reason the language you use considers `true` falsey and `false` truthy

Comment: @StephenS Will do

Comment: @Mayube thanks, sorry, I forgot to add "could you" in front of that xD

Comment: I suggest you add a test case: `puzzle`. This will make solutions that do the whole length of the string modulo 3, then negated (which works for all the current test cases) invalid.

Comment: @ComradeSparklePony will do

Comment: Do you require the 2 output values to be consistent?

Comment: Just curious, is there a way to define new functions in 2Col?

Comment: @Qwerp-Derp not yet, I'm planning to add a feature that will allow you to jump to another line, and then another that will allow you to jump back, meaning you could define functions that way

Comment: Isn't `from functools import reduce;` unnecessary? And also... semicolons?

Answer (score 6):

## [Brachylog](https://github.com/JCumin/Brachylog) (2), 4 bytes

```
ṇl₂ᵐ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/brachylog2#@/9wZ3vOo6amh1sn/P@vpGXBpW3IFVyoBAA)

Full program (because this is a [decision-problem](/questions/tagged/decision-problem); Brachylog full programs output `false.` if there was an assertion failure, `true.` without one).

### Explanation

```
ṇl₂ᵐ
ṇ     Split input into lines
   ᵐ  For each line:
 l₂     Assert that that line has length 2
```

Subscripts on `l` are one of Brachylog's newest features (although still older than the challenge), and this is a good challenge to use them on.

Comment: Although `ṇlᵛ2` and `ṇlᵛ²` would also work.

Answer (score 3):

## JavaScript (ES6), <s>24</s> <s>28</s> <s>25</s> 24 bytes

Fixed program and shaved of three bytes thanks to @PunPun1000

Shaved off one byte thanks to @Shaggy

```
s=>/^(..\n)*..$/.test(s)
```

Returns true if valid and false if not.

```js
f=
s=>/^(..\n)*..$/.test(s)

t=
`22
22
22
22
22`

console.log(f(t));
console.log(f(t.slice(0, -1)));
```

Comment: Just looking at this I don't think it works for two of the test cases (the truthy one with only 2 characters and no new line, and the falsey one with a trailing newline).  However `s=>s.match(/^(..\n)*..$/)` should correctly match both of those while also being shorter at 25 bytes

Comment: @PunPun1000 thank you, you are correct.

Comment: Unfortunately this is invalid as the 2 output values aren't consistent. However, you should be able to fix that *and* save a byte by using `test` instead of `match`.

Comment: @Shaggy thanks - the reason I didn't see that when I answered because that was just edited in

Comment: I know, that's why I pointed it out ;) You might want to update the note on your return values.

Answer (score 2):

## Haskell, <s>23</s> <s>52</s> 32 bytes

```
all((==2).length).lines.(++"\n")
```

I got my inspiration from some other solutions, clever trick adding that `"\n"`.

Comment: I've fixed it, but RIP my short solution.

Answer (score 2):

## [Cubix](https://github.com/ETHproductions/cubix), 20 bytes

Returns 1 for truthy and nothing for falsey

```
@1OuABq>;;?w-!$@;U_N
```

Cubified

```
    @ 1
    O u
A B q > ; ; ? w
- ! $ @ ; U _ N
    . .
    . .
```

- `ABq` slurp in all the input, reverse it and push the EOI(-1) to the bottom of the stack
- `>;;` Step into the loop and remove items from the stack
- `?` Test for EOI(-1).

  - If found `1uO@` push 1 to the stack, u-turn onto integer output and halt
  - Otherwise `_` reflect back onto the `?` which redirects to the `w` lane shift
- `N-!$@;U` push line feed (10) onto the stack, subtract, test result, skip the halt if false, remove the result and u-turn
- `;;>` remove the line feeds from the stack and redirect into the loop.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/cubix#@@9g6F/q6FRoZ21tX66rqOJgHRrv9/@/lgWXtiFXcCEA)

Answer (score 2):

## Python, 51

```
lambda s:all(len(l)==2for l in(s+"\n").splitlines())
```

Test case runner:

```
tcs = {
    "F!\n$^": 1,
    "*8\n+1\nSq": 1,
    "nop\nxt": 0,
    "+1\n+1\n#^\n": 0,
    "": 0,
    "ye": 1,
    "no ": 0,
    "test": 0,
    "puzzle": 0
}
f = lambda s:all(len(l)==2for l in(s+"\n").splitlines())
for tc, expected in tcs.items():
    assert f(tc) == expected
```

Answer (score 1):

## JavaScript (ES6), <s>35</s> 24 bytes

```js
s=>!/^.?$|.../gm.test(s)
```

---

### Try it

```js
f=
s=>!/^.?$|.../gm.test(s)
oninput=_=>o.innerText=f(i.value)
o.innerText=f(i.value=`F!
$^`)
```

```html
<textarea id=i></textarea><pre id=o>
```

Comment: `There's gotta be a shorter way to do this with RegEx!` [Yup](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/122778/65836) (and mine is probably not optimal)

Answer (score 1):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), <s>7</s> 6 bytes

```
·eÈÊ¶2
```

[Try it online](https://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.5&code=t2XIyrYy&input=IkYhClNeIg==)

---

### Explanation

```
     :Implicit input of string "U"
·    :Split to array on newline
eÈ   :Maps over the array, checking that every item's ...
Ê    :length ...
¶2   :Equals 2
     :Implicit output of result
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 6 bytes

```
ỴL€=2Ṃ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/jelly#@/9w9xafR01rbI0e7mz6//9/Xn4BV0UJAA)

**Explanation:**

```
ỴL€=2Ṃ
Ỵ       Split at newlines
 L€     Length of each...
   =2   ...equals two.
     Ṃ  Minimum.
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Retina](https://github.com/m-ender/retina), 10 bytes

```
^..(¶..)*$
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/retina#@x@np6dxaJuenqaWyv//AA) Outputs `1` or `0` as appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

## [Java (OpenJDK 8)](http://openjdk.java.net/), 25 bytes

```java
s->s.matches("(..\n)*..")
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/java-openjdk#jc@xTgMxDADQOfmKcDAkLVhiq1TowNCN6UZCJXPNlaCcExpf1VPVbz@uancyWI7sZytO/VfwjWoC5qze0ZM6SZGuxczIUzpEv1Xd1NI17z3tPj4V7nfZnKQU4gcPCD37AG1PDftIsL49Xq788S3G4JBWqlWvcsxPqwwdcvPtsq40gCUzA6jMKMRyWlgPmV0HsWdI0zgH0i1gSmHQ1frO0sOmMuY/OFtYmj9bqn8LMMVk6cgF8rLyEvcbSwW8gAyu6IOqQLHLtxvO8jz@AQ)

Checks if the input string has any number of lines followed by a line feed and a final line without one (ensures at least one line)

Answer (score 1):

## [J-uby](https://github.com/cyoce/j-uby), <s>19</s> 18 bytes

```
:=~&/^(..\n*)..$/m
```

`:=~&` makes an anonymous function that takes `x` and returns `0` if it matches the regex `/^(..\n*)..$/m`, or `nil` otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 6 bytes

```
¶¡D2ùQ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/05ab1e#@39o26GFLkaHdwb@/6@kpOSmyKUSB6QB)

```
¶¡D2ùQ   Argument s
¶¡       Split s on newlines
  D      Duplicate
   2ù    Keep only elements of length 2
     Q   Compare
```

Answer (score 0):

## Bash + GNU utilities, 13

```
grep -qv ^..$
```

This sets the shell return value (accessible in `$?`) to 0 for false and 1 for true.  This is actually the opposite sense [compared to normal shell convention](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11924/new-users-guides-to-golfing-rules-in-specific-languages/12026#12026), so to make that right you'd need to do:

## Bash + GNU utilities, 15

```
! grep -qv ^..$
```

Answer (score 0):

## Ruby, 22 bytes

```rb
->s{s=~/^(..\n*)..$/m}
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 5 bytes

```
ỴẈ=2Ȧ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///h7i0Pd3XYGp1Y9v///7z8Aq6KEgA)

A small improvement over the other jelly answer.

### Explanation

```
ỴẈ=2Ȧ Main Link: takes string on the left
Ỵ     split on newlines
 Ẉ    length(vectorizes)
  =2  equals 2? (vectorizes)
    Ȧ are all elements truthy?
```